# GWT: Using UIBinder with HTML templates... how to get it to work?

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I am currently trying to use GWT's UIBinder functionality, but without success. I have read the documentation several times, but it does NOT contain the full story. Maybe you can help me.

Here is what I know so far:

1) I need to create e.g. a HelloWorld.ui.xml file with some widget layout in.
2) I need to create a corresponding HelloWorld class.

Here is what I can't find info about:

A) Where do I put the HelloWorld.ui.xml file, to enable GWT to find it?

B) How to I add my HelloWorld component to e.g. a panel?

The documentation is very scarce, and definately written by someone who already knows too much about GWT to see, what a newbie doesn't know.

Comment: Also, install the [Google Plugin for Eclipse](http://code.google.com/eclipse/), it will take care of most of that work (you just put the Components name and it will create the corresponding java and ui.xml files).... [among other things](http://code.google.com/eclipse/docs/gwt.html) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A) You need to put the `HelloWorld.ui.xml` file in the same package as the widget class which contains the logic for that ui.xml file. The class name should be `HelloWorld` (for sake of simplicity I say you need to use the same name, but it's possible via code to use a different name for the ui.xml file.)

B) Your `HelloWorld` class should be a class extending a widget. Just like any 'normal' widget it can than added to any panel.

Here is the code to bind the `HelloWorld.ui.xml` to in your `HelloWorld` widget class:

```
public class HelloWorld extends Composite /*or extend any widget you want*/ {
    //This defines an interface that represents this specific HelloWorld.ui.xml file.
    interface MyUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, HelloWorld> {}

    // This code is for GWT so it can generate the code from your HelloWorld.ui.xml
    private static MyUiBinder uiBinder = GWT.create(MyUiBinder.class);

    //Constructor
    public HelloWidgetWorld() {
        // This binds the HelloWorld.ui.xml with this widget
        initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This overview explains everything: http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html

1. You put HelloWorld.ui.xml in the same folder as your HelloWorld.java file.
2. Like this (taken from above link):

   ```
   public class HelloWorld extends UIObject { // Could extend Widget instead
       interface HelloWorldUiBinder extends UiBinder<DivElement, HelloWorld> {}
       private static HelloWorldUiBinder uiBinder =  
             GWT.create(HelloWorldUiBinder.class);

       // div element created via UiBinder
       private DivElement divElement;

       public HelloWorld() {
           // createAndBindUi 
           divElement = uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this);
           // now you can add created DivElement to your panel
       }
   };
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Here are two complete tutorials and HelloWorld samples:

1) for UI Binder with GWT control: 
    http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2010/01/19/gwt-uibinder-hello-world-tutorial/

2) for UI Binder with plain HTML:
   Oops! StackOverflow doesn't let me post two hyperlinks.  So I will post the second one in a separate answer, or a in a comment to this one.

Comment: Here is the link to the plain HTML sample: http://blog.iparissa.com/gwt-uibinder-helloworld-with-html/